# How to use html.textboxfor for numbers in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC web app, having a model class ***student.cs***

which has properties ***name, address, points*** where points is an integer. in view I am trying to use:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.points) %>
```

The compiler cannot accept it.
how to use Html.TextBoxFor for integers?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. and when i tried to convert it, BANGG –

Comment: Can you show the model class?

Comment: public class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
        }

        //constructor :)
        public Student(int ID, int repPoints)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.repPoints = repPoints;
        }
        
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int repPoints { get; set;  }

    }

Comment: still i have many other properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new ASP.NET MVC project and use only the code you presented:

you will see that it works.

**View**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.Student>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.repPoints) %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Model**

```
public class Student 
{ 
public Student() { } //constructor :) 

public Student(int ID, int repPoints) 

{ this.ID = ID; this.repPoints = repPoints; } 

public int ID { get; set; } 

public int repPoints { get; set; } }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Student student = new Student(10, 20);

            return View(student);
        }

        public ActionResult UpdateStudent(Student student)
        {
            //access the DB here

            return View("Index",student);
        }


    }
```

Comment: this works, but actually i dowanna set ID to 10 nor repPoints to 20, all i want to do is to set them dynamically, so that repPoints value will be taken from view

Comment: see the changed controller. you can post the form to UpdateStudent and student will have the values the user entered

Answer (score 2):

If you only want numbers with minimum value 1 you can do it like this: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new {@type = "number", @min = "1"})`

Answer (score 1):

<s>You need to cast the integer to a string</s>

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.points.ToString())

**Edit:** 
The code should work. A very simple test

The model

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {              
    var model = new Product {Id = 10};
    return View(model);
 }
```

The view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)
```

Comment: then it says: Invalid Operation Exception// Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. and when i tried to convert it, BANGG

Comment: Stick a watch in Visual Studio and see what the value of model.points is

Comment: in the model class, points is a property, and i used: <%=Html.TextBoxFor(s => Convert.ToString(s.repPoints)) still, the error message: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.